# How to handle AutoHotKey "suspend" in Python

Tags: python, autohotkey

I'd like to convert this AHK script into a Python script, but I really don't understand this `suspend` on AHK, can somebody help please?

```
LButton::
Send {WheelDown}
return

F2::Suspend
```

Here's my Python script, but it doesn't run:

```
import pyautogui
import keyboard
import time

def simulate_wheel_down():
    pyautogui.scroll(-1)  # Simulate wheel down action

def on_left_click(event):
    if event.event_type == keyboard.KEY_DOWN:
        if event.name == 'mouse left':
            simulate_wheel_down()

def stop_script(event):
    if event.event_type == keyboard.KEY_DOWN and event.name == 'f2':
        print("Script stopped by user.")
        exit()

# Start listening for left mouse click and F2 key events
keyboard.hook(on_left_click)
keyboard.hook(stop_script)

try:
    # Keep the script running
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    # Stop listening when the script is interrupted (e.g., by pressing Ctrl+C)
    keyboard.unhook_all()
```

Comment: "Suspend" means that AHK stops processing all other hot keys defined in the script, except the one to turn suspension off.

Comment: Maybe you can try ```keyboard.add_hotkey(hotkey, callback, args=(), suppress=False, timeout=1, trigger_on_release=False)``` this method with suppress=True.
With "mouse" python library.